# Page indicator and title in Navigation Bar iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, pagecontrol

i want to create a navigation bar in which I have a `pageControl` as well as the Title in the navigation bar just like the twitter iOS app contains, I got them both by setting the

```
self.navigationItem.Title = @"Home";
```

and achieved the `PageControl` by creating an instance of `UIPageControl` and setting its centre to the centre of the navigation bar and achieving its navigation detection by using the `UINavigationController's` Delegate. But the problem is that the pageControl and the title are overlapping each other.. how can I set it like this that the Title should appear on the top of page indicator. Here is the code of the positioning the `pageControl`.

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;  
CGSize navBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size;  
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake( navBarSize.width/2, navBarSize.height/2 );  
self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y,
                                                                   0, 0)];  
[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:3];  
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.pageControl];

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
int index = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];  
self.pageControl.currentPage = index;  }
```

Comment: you can try to create an UIView and add to it UILabel with title and UIPageControl, then add this UIView in navigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, both (the title and the pageControl) were overlapping each other so i just changed the Y-Axis of the pageControl and

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;  
CGSize navBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size;  
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake( navBarSize.width/2, navBarSize.height/2 );  
self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y+45,
                                                               0, 0)]; //Here added 45 to Y and it did the trick 
[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:3];  
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.pageControl];

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
int index = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];  
self.pageControl.currentPage = index;  }
```